# C# .NET Trying to get a path of a project resource file

Tags: c#, .net

This is my first post because I could not find any solution for my problem. Neither for myself nor in any thread.

Here is the situation. I do have a .JSON file which stores my credentials for an API authentification.
The software is used on multiple computers, so please do not propose anything regarding a hardcoded path.

My code:

```
string path = Path.GetTempPath();
            path = path + "unterschrift.png";
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path) == false)
            {
                Properties.Resources.credentials.Save(path);
            }
```

Now I do get the error: byte[] does not contain a definition for "Save"

Looking for your support!

The same code worked for an image file but not now because it is a different file format. I have already tried decoding the byte but it does not work.

Comment: The code makes no sense, do focus on what you tried to accomplish.

Comment: Could you then may help me how to further proceed with the problem? Regarding the byte to string error

Comment: If the file is stored in different places on different machines, how do expect to be able to find it? You'd need to explain more detail before anyone can help you.

Comment: As I have mentioned the file is stored into the project as a resource. I already showed up a code example with an image, where I was able to get the path. The problem now is the byte to string error.